# How to replace string pattern with sequential number?

Tags: ruby

I have a string pattern `NNNNNN` and an integer `1`.

How can I replace that pattern with the next sequential integer and fill up the rest with zeros, so I get this string:

`000002`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How the pattern affect the result? Is just the number of zeros or could be different chars within?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`rjust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-rjust):

```
counter = 1
pattern = 'NNNNNN'

counter.succ.to_s.rjust(pattern.length, '0')
#=> "000002"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean it that way:

```
 start_str = '0' * 'NNNNNN'.length
 puts start_str.succ
```

Or

```
 pattern_len = 'NNNNNN'.length
 start_value = 1
 puts format("%0#{pattern_len}d", start_value +1)
```